# Fill pattern not expanded to all cells

Tags: r, ggplot2, fill, facet-grid

I am filling the cells of a matrix with a color according to the value of the number in the cell.

Some example data:

```
plotData <- structure(list(Dimension = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Dim 1", "Dim 2", "Dim 3", 
"Dim 4", "Dim 5", "Dim 6", "Dim 7"), class = "factor"), R1 = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 
6L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 
3L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 2L, 
2L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("Rater 1", 
"Rater 2", "Rater 3", "Rater 4", "Rater 5", "Rater 6", "Rater 7"
), class = "factor"), R2 = structure(c(4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
3L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 
6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
2L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("Rater 1", "Rater 2", "Rater 3", 
"Rater 4", "Rater 5", "Rater 6", "Rater 7"), class = "factor"), 
    kappa = c(0.607540983606557, 0.437185929648241, 0.731739272846381, 
    0.534769230769231, 0.498230088495575, 0.503184713375796, 
    0.189421015010722, 0.24248496993988, 0.196913787319691, 0.188524590163934, 
    0.71434460016488, 0.583883751651255, 0.676277476448758, 0.597444089456869, 
    0.630104083266613, 0.390125847047435, 0.265364008824456, 
    0.269453768690876, 0.12396449704142, 0.378727400798309, 0.567901234567901, 
    0.591351351351351, 0.630104083266613, 0.471698113207547, 
    0.185430463576159, 0.094765651727677, 0.348789131718842, 
    0.167259786476868, 0.784320438206094, 0.616555082166768, 
    0.130634774609016, 0.207547169811321, 0.160714285714286, 
    0.135011441647597, 0.533908754623921, 0.505882352941176, 
    0.198526950117174, 0.199491740787802, 0.121372031662269, 
    0.446559297218155, 0.313291139240506, 0.488774682174736, 
    0.607540983606557, 0.437185929648241, 0.731739272846381, 
    0.534769230769231, 0.498230088495575, 0.503184713375796, 
    0.189421015010722, 0.24248496993988, 0.196913787319691, 0.188524590163934, 
    0.71434460016488, 0.583883751651255, 0.676277476448758, 0.597444089456869, 
    0.630104083266613, 0.390125847047435, 0.265364008824456, 
    0.269453768690876, 0.12396449704142, 0.378727400798309, 0.567901234567901, 
    0.591351351351351, 0.630104083266613, 0.471698113207547, 
    0.185430463576159, 0.094765651727677, 0.348789131718842, 
    0.167259786476868, 0.784320438206094, 0.616555082166768, 
    0.130634774609016, 0.207547169811321, 0.160714285714286, 
    0.135011441647597, 0.533908754623921, 0.505882352941176, 
    0.198526950117174, 0.199491740787802, 0.121372031662269, 
    0.446559297218155, 0.313291139240506, 0.488774682174736, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 6L, 7L, 11L, 12L, 16L, 17L, 21L, 22L, 26L, 27L, 31L, 32L, 
36L, 37L, 41L, 42L, 46L, 47L, 51L, 52L, 56L, 57L, 61L, 62L, 66L, 
67L, 71L, 72L, 76L, 77L, 81L, 82L, 86L, 87L, 91L, 92L, 96L, 97L, 
101L, 102L, 106L, 107L, 111L, 112L, 116L, 117L, 121L, 122L, 126L, 
127L, 131L, 132L, 136L, 137L, 141L, 142L, 146L, 147L, 151L, 152L, 
156L, 157L, 161L, 162L, 166L, 167L, 171L, 172L, 176L, 177L, 181L, 
182L, 186L, 187L, 191L, 192L, 196L, 197L, 201L, 202L, 206L, 207L, 
211L, 212L, 216L, 217L, 221L, 222L, 226L, 227L, 231L, 232L, 236L, 
237L, 241L, 242L, 246L, 247L, 251L, 252L, 256L, 257L, 261L, 262L, 
266L, 267L, 271L, 272L, 276L, 277L, 281L, 282L, 286L, 287L, 291L, 
292L, 296L, 297L, 301L, 302L, 306L, 307L, 311L, 312L, 316L, 317L, 
321L, 322L, 326L, 327L, 331L, 332L, 336L, 337L, 341L, 342L, 346L, 
347L, 351L, 352L, 356L, 357L, 361L, 362L, 366L, 367L, 371L, 372L, 
376L, 377L, 381L, 382L, 386L, 387L), class = "data.frame")
```

Now, this code should (I think) fill the cells with a color according to the kappa-value in the cell:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)    
p <- ggplot(plotData,aes(x=R1,y=R2)) + 
      geom_tile(aes(fill = kappa))  +
      geom_text(aes(label = round(kappa, 2))) +
      labs(x="",y="",fill="Kappa") + 
      labs_pubr(base_size = 15) +
      facet_grid(Dimension ~ .)

plot(p)
```

However, what I get is this:

[image]

so not all cells are coloured. I can't see why this would not work actually, but I am probably doing something stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because of wrong data formating - every combination (`R1` & `R2` is given twice, while one of the entries has `NA`).

Here we see that `R1 == "Rater 1" & R2 == "Rater 2"` combination is given twice with one of them having `NA`'s.

```
subset(plotData, R1 == "Rater 1" & R2 == "Rater 2")
   Dimension      R1      R2     kappa
1:     Dim 1 Rater 1 Rater 2 0.1213720
2:     Dim 2 Rater 1 Rater 2 0.4465593
3:     Dim 1 Rater 1 Rater 2        NA
4:     Dim 2 Rater 1 Rater 2        NA
```

`geom_text` uses `kappa` numeric value, however `fill` takes `NA` and that's why you're getting grey background.

To fix it use `na.omit()` on your data when plotting (you still won't be able to use `NA` values):

```
ggplot(na.omit(plotData), aes(R1, R2)) + 
      geom_tile(aes(fill = kappa))  +
      geom_text(aes(label = round(kappa, 2))) +
      facet_grid(Dimension ~ .)
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure that this was the actual problem, but my modified code now works so thanks!